# A few tables in one chart use amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have one question for You.
Data for my chart looks like:

```
var chartDataFull=[]
chartData1=[{category:1, value:2},{category:2, value:3},{category:3, value:6}];
chartData2=[{category:1, value:5},{category:2, value:1},{category:3, value:2}];
chartData3=[{category:1, value:3},{category:2, value:9},{category:3, value:7}];

chartDataFull.push(chartData1, chartData2, chartData3);
```

I would like all three table to put on one chart (different "value" same field "category") with amchart. Each will be represented by a separate column. How can do I do this?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle example?

Comment: Wait a moment, i will add.

Comment: Ok, http://jsfiddle.net/Cww3D/445/ here is chart with one data. How do I add columns for the other chartData (chartData2 and chartData3) for this chart.

Comment: A little note. The number of arrays of data (chartData) is dynamically generated, they are not static. Therefore, all adds up to a single array.

Comment: Ok, I'll do my best. I think that you can only display them separatly. What do you think of this. Change the index of  chart.dataProvider... http://jsfiddle.net/Cww3D/447/

Comment: Ok. I think I got you, give me 10 minutes...

Comment: It seems that only this fiddle that I' ve provided works for now. I'll definitely look it again in 2 hours when I come back from work if someone else doesn't solve the problem by then.

Comment: I will be grateful. Thank you for your interest in the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code to fill the graph (access your multidimensional array by index):

```
var chartDataFull=[]
chartData1=[{category:1, value:2},{category:2, value:3},{category:3, value:6}];
chartData2=[{category:1, value:5},{category:2, value:1},{category:3, value:2}];
chartData3=[{category:1, value:3},{category:2, value:9},{category:3, value:7}];

chartDataFull.push(chartData1);
chartDataFull.push(chartData2);
chartDataFull.push(chartData3);
```

**FIRST SOLUTION:**

Display only one dataset inside the graph with the option of switching in between them.

Code:

> chart.dataProvider = chartDataFull[1]; //switch your index here if you
>   want another graph based on datasets. Range (0-2).

```
  chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.autoMarginOffset = 0;
    chart.dataProvider = chartDataFull[1]
    chart.categoryField = "category";
    chart.startDuration = 1;
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cww3D/448/

**SECOND SOLUTION**

This solution get's closest to your need's. This is done by concataneting your array's. You've mentioned that your arrays are not static, still you can adjust it with the concat() function to suit your needs.

Code:

```
chartDataFull.push(chartData1);
chartDataFull.push(chartData2);
chartDataFull.push(chartData3);
var children = chartData1.concat(chartData2,chartData3);
```

URL fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/Cww3D/452/

**OFFICIAL EXAMPLE**

fiddle example:

URL fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/u3ypB/

You can see that when they are displaying the other dataset, they are placing it in another chart.

**Conclusion:**

Unfortunately once you populate your *dataset* using the *dataProvider* attribute that's pretty much it. You've created the graph and you can not modify it in a way to insert additional data. Once this operation attribute is filled your are done with data population.

Comment: Impressive answer! Thank You for it, but .. hmm this is not what I'm looking for. Maybe change type of chart for this: http://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/php4.png can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I doubt that, maybe if you switch to another chart js?. I've looked at the docs a little bit more but nothing that would do it.

Comment: Hmmm then .. do You have any proposal to change amchart to another chart js?

Comment: @mdk you have to google yourself, I can suggest zingchart, highchart,chart.js..., more on charts here: http://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/